# Is this the correct solve for CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED exception?

Tags: c#, ssl, xamarin, xamarin.android, lets-encrypt

So I'm currently making an Xamarin.Android app, and for a while now it has used my REST API that I made to communicate with data back and forth.

However I recently switched my SSL certificate over to LetsEncrypt which caused the following exception when trying to communicate with my API from my app:

```
Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

Which I assume means it didn't get verified correctly. I found the following snippet below which verifies the request from my domain only and passes it through, and this works.

However my question is. Is this secure? Could this potentially lead to a Man in the middle attack, or am I ok?

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicy) =>
{
    if (sslPolicy == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        return true;

    if (sslPolicy == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors &&
       ((HttpWebRequest)sender).RequestUri.Authority.Equals("MY_API_DOMAIN"))
        return true;

    return false;
};
```

Comment: Which API level(s) device(s) are failing? And are you using the AndroidClientHandler? and/or the BoringSSL/TLS impl.? And yes, spoofing a domain name in a MITM attack is easy... (FYI: I use the `mitmproxy` all the time to decode/debug SSL traffic, it is easy as pie for apps that do not pin certs.)

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm using AndroidHttpClientHandler and Native TLS 1.2+. I have also tried the other combinations of the Managed HttpClient from .NET and other types of TLS. All of the combinations give me the same error.

Comment: @SushiHangover I do not know that. (EDIT: I am using ASP.NET tho)

Comment: LetsEncrypt is not typically a client problem unless you are talking really old devices (that do not support SHA2, TLS1.2, etc...), and by old I mean original WinXP, Android 2.x, etc... I would *assume* your server is not replying with the correct ciphers and/or (but most likely) it is not replying with the intermediate certificate. Not sure about asp.net as I never expose it to the public internet, but using Apache|Nginx as the reverse proxy, you need to use the full chain pem file (that is a combo of chain plus your cert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way to solve this is definitely not secure: you are essentially accepting arbitrary certificates as long as the request is for a specific domain in the URL. This means a man in the middle attacker could simply intercept all traffic to this specific server, present you with his own fake certificate and sniff or even modify the data without your application noticing.

If your server works without problems with a browser it is more likely that your application/system either does not trust the Let's Encrypt CA or (more likely) that your server is setup improperly and does not send a required intermediate certificate. Please check the server against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for problems like *incomplete chain*.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this albeit a tad late after the above answer.  In my case, my cert passed the checks - even some Android devices worked but the issue was a server issue despite getting passing marks for certificate installation.

In the case of the server configuration, you must support "forward secrecy"  Otherwise you will get the error above on some Android devices while others work.

Hope this helps someone.